# SQL Server joining two tables counting

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count

I want to join table 1 and table 2 by counting the people in table two who visited the combo in table 1, so the result would look like

**table 1**

```
City1  City2

Rome   Berlin 
Moscow Berlin
```

....many more rows  (to be clear- this was just an excerpt)
**table 2**

```
Person City

Peter Rome
Peter Paris
Peter Berlin
Peter Moscow
Paul  Rome
Paul  Moscow
Mary  London
Mary  Moscow
Mary  Berlin
```

... many more rows

**What I want it to look like:**

```
Rome   Berlin 0
Moscow Berlin 3
London Berlin 1
```

Any help appreciated.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
select a.city1
     , a.city2
     , count(case when city=a.city1 and city=a.city2 THEN city ELSE NULL END) 
from table1 a join table2 b
```

Comment: Include what you've tried so far.

Comment: Hi, your sample data is incorrect. There is no `London Berlin` combination in table1... I would recommend reading [ask] as well; we generally expect you do have done something to solve the problem yourself before posting.

Comment: select a.city1, a.city2, count(case when city=a.city1 and city=a.city2   THEN city ELSE NULL END) from table1 a join table2 b

Comment: I am pretty new to this complex of coding - I usually just merge table  or count separately before merging. I am a bit at a loss how I do this dynamically with out pivoting the table2 around and do a complicated search. thanks.

Comment: @user3254601 . . . This is a much better question with the sample data and desired results.

Comment: This will be helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this is by joining to each of the cities and then aggregating, counting up when there is a match in both tables.  This form of the query assumes there are no duplicates in the second table:

```
select t1.city1, t2.city2,
       sum(case when t21.person is not null and t22.person is not null then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from table1 t1 left outer join
     table2 t21
     on t1.city1 = t21.city left outer join
     table2 t22
     on t1.city1 = t22.city and t22.person = t21.person
group by t1.city1, t2.city2;
```

EDIT:

You can also do this with two levels of aggregation and one join.  This is pretty easy to explain.  The inner query counts the number of cities that a person matches for each pair of cities.  The `cnt` is 0, 1, or 2.  The outer query then counts the number where `cnt = 2`, because these are the ones that match both cities.

```
select city1, city2, sum(case when cnt = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from (select t1.city1, t2.city2, person, count(t2.person) as cnt
      from table1 t1 left outer join
           table2 t2
           on t2.city in (t1.city1, t1.city2);
```

The advantage of this approach is that adding new cities is easy, as well as getting more information, such as how many people match exactly one of the cities.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Like I said I am relatively new to this and like to learn how to do it right and was stuck. Glad you took the time!

Answer (score 0):

Sample data is incorrect, no `London-Berlin` combination in table1 and result should be

```
Rome    Berlin  1
Moscow  Berlin  2
London  Berlin  1
```

However it can be achieved: you want the combinations of the cities of table2 so join table2 to itself based on person.

You also want to mach the combinations in table1 so join table1 to the previous result.

You need a counter so group on the last resultset:

```
select t2.city, t3.city, count(t1.city1) as counter 
from table2 as t2
inner join table2 as t3 on t2.person = t3.person and t2.city <> t3.city
inner join table1 as t1 on t1.city1 = t2.city and t1.city2 = t3.city
group by t2.city, t3.city
```

The result will be as requested but you have to enter correct data in table1, otherwise you can get wrong result.